# Как можно упростить данный код на с++?

Tags: c++

**Задача:** *В одномерном целочисленном массиве (размер массива (не больше 20) и значения его элементов вводить с клавиатуры) вычислить сумму элементов массива, расположенных после последнего элемента, равного нулю.*

Сама задача была решена, но мне кажется ее можно написать горазде проще (не приходит в голову как).

```
int main()
{
int arr[20], len,nul, sum=0, b=0;
puts("input a array lenght");
scanf("%d", &len);

// filling the array with data
puts("input a array element");
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    if (arr[i] != 0) {
        b++;
    } 

for (int i = len; i > 0; i--)
    if (arr[i] == 0) {
        nul = i;
        break;
    }

for (int i = nul; i < len; i++)
    sum += arr[i];


if (b == len)
    printf("not zero values");
else 
    printf("%d", sum);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ее можно написать без массива и только с одним циклом, главное считать сумму на ходу и сбрасывать если на вход придет 0.

Comment: Массив и его заполнение является обязательным условием.

Comment: В тексте условия, который вы привели, об этом ничего не сказано.

Comment: > В одномерном целочисленном массиве.
Я правильно Вас понял:  итерироваться по массиву в обратном порядке, пока i != 0?

Comment: Всё равно в процессе ввода можно уже считать сумму и обнулять при 0 на входе... 1 цикл сэкономишь

Comment: Я Вас понял, спасибо!

Comment: То, что на вход подаются элементы из "в одномерном целочисленном массиве" не подразумевает, что программа обязательно должна хранить у себя в памяти этот массив. Массив не нужен, достаточно одного цикла, обрабатывающего по одному элементу из этого массива по мере ввода.

Comment: И если это С++, то почему не использовать `cout/cin` вместо `printf/scanf`?

Answer (score 2):

Вообще это делается в одну строку, просто массив надо просматривать с конца.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0 && arr[i] != 0; --i) sum += arr[i];
```

Comment: А если 0 вообще не встретится?

Comment: @avp, тогда просто сосчитается сумма всех элементов.

Comment: А вот если `int i` вынести из for `(...)`, то можно легко отловить этот случай и сообщить о нем.

Comment: @avp, можно, но зачем? В условии задачи этого нет, да и вообще логичней в этом случае считать общую сумму.

Comment: Ну, при таком подходе, как говорится *no comments...*

Comment: @avp, не понял что вас не устроило в этом подходе. С чего вы вообще взяли, что отсутствие нуля есть ошибка данных? По-моему, так это нормальная ситуация и выдавать какие-то сообщения как раз и будет ошибкой.

Comment: Вы, скажем, Майерса (Искусство тестирования программ) читали?

Comment: @avp, не собираюсь устраивать тут чатик с болтовней на отвлеченные темы. Не можете обосновать свою точку зрения, значит вопрос закрыт, говорить не о чем.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = len; i > 0; i--)
    if (arr[i] == 0) {
        nul = i;
        break;
    }
```

Здесь ошибка - выход за пределы массива. Можно исправить так:

```
for (int i = len; i > 0; ) {
    -- i ;
    if (arr[i] == 0) {
        nul = i;
        break; }    }
```

Ошибка вторая : не проверяются корректные данные размера **len**. Обязательно сделать примерно так :

```
scanf("%d", &len);
if(len<0 || len > 20) return 1;
```

Ошибка третья : переменная **nul** не иницилизирована никаким значением, там значение будет случайным. И при отсутствии нулей программа благополучно обрушится или будет результат неопределённый. Суммировать можно только после проверки, что нашли нуль какой-нибудь.

```
if (b == len)
    printf("not zero values");
else {
    for (int i = nul; i < len; i++)
        sum += arr[i];
    printf("%d", sum); }
```

Насчёт упрощения программы - ещё рано.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  const int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

  using RevIt = std::reverse_iterator<const int *>;
  RevIt rev_b(std::end(a)), rev_e(std::begin(a));
  RevIt rev_z = std::find(rev_b, rev_e, 0);

  if (rev_z != rev_e)
    std::cout << std::accumulate(rev_b, rev_z, 0) << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "No zeros" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> varr;// = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
     { 
        int a;
        cin >> a;
        varr.push_back(a);
     }
    int result = 0;
    auto it = find_if(varr.rbegin(), varr.rend(), [&result](const int& a) -> bool {
        if (a == 0) return true;
        result += a;
        return false;
    });

    if (it == varr.rend())
        cout << "No zero values";
    else
        cout << result;

    return 0;
}
```